# The getter 'loadingStatus' was called on null flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-test

**hi**

i got error in flutter

it's just get loading status from provider i has the same error in all providers i used

> The getter 'loadingStatus' was called on null flutter

> **This error appears only in console but app works fine -_-**

```
class _DoctorInfoPageState extends State<DoctorInfoPage> {
  GeneralService _generalService;
  ProfileService _profileService;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _generalService = Provider.of<GeneralService>(context);
      _profileService = Provider.of<ProfileService>(context);
      loadingReviews();
    });
  }

  loadingReviews() async {
    _generalService.setLoadingState(true);
    await _profileService.getReviews(context);
    _generalService.setLoadingState(false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon:
              Icon(Icons.chevron_left, size: 30, color: Const.appMainBlueColor),
          onPressed: () {
            print('test');
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Doctor Info",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Const.appMainBlueColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
      body: _generalService.loadingStatus != null &&
              _generalService.loadingStatus
          ? Center(child: PumpHeart(size: 35.0))
          : SafeArea()
);
  }
}
```

i tried more and more but nothing changed so can ant one told me where the error please ?

This is the provider code

```
class GeneralService with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  // Change Loading Status
  void setLoadingState(bool value) {
    _isLoading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // Get Loading Status
  bool get loadingStatus => _isLoading;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` will be called one frame later (as a Future for the next frame), because of that the first frame where it builds `_generalService.loadingStatus` _generalService it's not referenced yet (you're caliing `null.loadingStatus`). If you want to keep that logic then just change it to `_generalService?.loadingStatus != null && _generalService.loadingStatus`

I dont know your classes but maybe it would be better to adapt `GeneralService` as a `ProxyProvider` of `ProfileService` or a `FutureProvider` of `_profileService.getReviews(context)`, but that's apart of the problem you're facing